# Logging into a website using PHPAuth/PHPAuth via Chrome Extension

Tags: php, authentication, google-chrome-extension

I have developed a Chrome Extension which calls some APIs on my website, which in turn uses PHPAuth/PHPAuth for authentication. Basically, I have the user enter the Username and Password for the website as an Extension Option and I call a Login API on my website as follows.

```
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];

                if($auth->isLogged()) {
                    $userId = $auth->getSessionUID($_COOKIE[$authConfig->cookie_name]);
                    echo json_encode([
                                'userId' => $userId,
                            ]);
                    die();
                }

                $login = $auth->login($email, $password, true);

                if($login['error']) {
                    die($login['message']);
                } else {
                    $userId = $auth->getSessionUID($login['hash']);
                    echo json_encode([
                                'userId' => $userId,
                            ]);
                    die();
                }
            } else {
                die('Error');
            }
```

This works to temporarily consider the user authenticated, but does not actually log the user into the website. In other words, when I open a password protected page via an iFrame, it shows me the User Login form.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, or a better way to go about what I need.

Basically, I am saving the user the need to keep logging in every time and open protected pages, once he is made to log in.

Comment: Probably related to cookies not being set/transferred inside iframe. Just guessing.

Comment: Your comment makes sense, but in that case wouldn't the page show up when refreshed for a second time? Doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check if manifest.json does contain your website URL and all required subdomains for example

```
"permissions": [
  "http://example.com/",
  "http://*.example.com/",
  "https://example.com/",
  "https://*.example.com/"
],
```

Also, you can communicate with website in a bit different way for example:

- first time when you login to your website it could return a token which you can store in the browser [local storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and on the server side against the user.
- This token should send later from the extension along with the request to your website.
- on the website side you should check if this token exists ; if it belongs to the right user ; and didn't expire. if is correct then perform requested by user action.

And to be honest much more secure would be to use [OAuth_2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0) which is more secure then username / password authentication within extension context

Comment: My manifest already has full permissions...

"permissions": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "storage", "webNavigation", "<all_urls>", "*://*/*" ],

Although, you are right oAuth would be better. Let's see whether we can fix this though, since I already opened this question.